# How can I get user clicks from a ViewPager2 that uses Fragment?

Tags: android, exception, button, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm looking forward to get a user's click on a Button that is inside a Fragment. I am using a ViewPager2 to swipe between the different Fragments.

In one of the Fragments I have a Button where I want to set an onClickListener, however when I try to set the Button's onClickListener on onOcreateView, I get this error:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
A/cifireca.words: java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at android.view.View cifireca.words.FragmentStock.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FragmentStock.java:40)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2600)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps() (BackStackRecord.java:434)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$OpGenerator, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow() (BackStackRecord.java:293)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentViewHolder) (FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentViewHolder) (FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
    java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder) (FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
```

I can see that It is indeed caused by the setOnClickListener, however I am not sure how I can solve this.

My way to implement the onClickListener is the following:

```
public class FragmentStock extends Fragment {
   ...
   private Button buttonAccept;
   ...
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock, container, false);
       ...
       buttonAccept = viewGroup.findViewWithTag(R.id.button_stockAccept);
       buttonAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               ... do whatever
           }
       });
       return viewGroup;
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findViewById` instead of `findViewWithTag` I think it should resolve your problem.

```
buttonAccept = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.button_stockAccept);
```

Comment: That worked! I've changed that before and forgot to reverse the change and I couldn't see that mistake. I'm really grateful! Thanks!